# how can i paste the pictures i downloaded to my computer in the images folder in my flutter project?

Tags: android, image, flutter, visual-studio

I opened the images folder, but when I right click on it, the paste option does not appear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H0PW.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all certify that you have indeed copied a file, maybe in your clipboard you have a text and VSCode will not allow you to paste it.
If that didn't work, you could always drag and drop, VSCode allows you to do that.

Comment: I was sure it was a file but for some reason I couldn't drag it.i found the file path and pasted my images there and this is how it happened